# NavtiveScript + Vue , preventing tap on beneath elements (Android)

Tags: nativescript

I have an app with two layers:

Layer **One** `(z-index:1, visible)` consists of 4 Labels `( A, B, C, D )` in 4 separated Layouts ( imports from Component L1 )

Layer **Two** `(z-index:2, hidden)` consists of 4 Labels `( E, F, G, H )` in 4 separated Layouts ( imports from Component L2 )

By tapping on **A**: Layer **Two** will be displayed.

By tapping on **E**: Layer **Two** will be hidden.

I want to :

disable Labels `( A, B, C, D )` while Layer **Two** is **visible**.

It seems that setting `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false` on each Label will helps, but I would like to find a method to deactive whole the Layer **One** at once, not by dectiving all Labels one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I noticed, If I put `@tap=""` on Layer **Two**, the parts of Layer **One** which are covered by Layer **Two**, will be de-activated!

Answer (score 0):

It's the default behaviour of Android, you will have to set `isUserInteractionEnabled` on each individual element to disable it.

You may just loop through all child elements of layout and set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to true / false as needed.